# Sqlite query to fetch rows for particular day

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I would like to fetch results for selected date using SQLITE DB, and am getting date from uidatepicker and passing to fetch results method.

My sqlite query is following,

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONSHISTORY WHERE DATE > "21-09-2014 12:00:00" AND DATE < "22-09-2014 00:00:00"
```

But for that am getting results in 2015 year also, kindly help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with details about how the `DATE` column is defined in your schema and if you show how you store date values in the column.

Answer (score 2):

Your date is not in the correct format, if you check the documentation (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) you will find this:

A time string can be in any of the following formats:

YYYY-MM-DD

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS

HH:MM

HH:MM:SS

HH:MM:SS.SSS

now

DDDDDDDDDD

If you make your date one of these formats, and run the query it will work:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONSHISTORY WHERE date BETWEEN '2014-09-21' AND '2014-09-22'
```

Comment: Actually SQLite does not interpret the dates: it just does string comparison. That's why the format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS' is very important: the lexicographical order or the strings that comply to this format is the same as the "natural" date order. On the opposite, the format 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' does not lexicographically sort dates, and that is why it must be avoided at all costs.

Comment: I solved this with custom query like searched the date between 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 with same date